# not just another 'column invalid in select list' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

i say this because i tried all the usual solutions and they just aren't working. here's what i have..

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp
(
    PrintData   nvarchar(250) NOT NULL, 
    Acronym     nvarchar(3) NOT NULL,
    Total       int not null
)
```

this is successfully populated using 3 SELECT's with a Group By unioned together

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Result
(
    PrintData   nvarchar(250) NOT NULL, 
    Acronym     nvarchar(3) NOT NULL,
    Total       int not null,
    [Percent]   decimal(7,5) not null
)
```

all i want to do is populate this table from Table 1 while adding the Percent column which i calculate using the following stmt..

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Result
    (PrintData, Acronym, Total, [Percent]) 
select *, ((t.Total / SUM(t.Total)) * 100) 
from Temp t 
group by PrintData, Acronym, Total
```

but the Percent col comes out as 0.00000 on every row
i thought it might have something to do with the group by but if i remove it, i get that stupid error i quoted.
some sample data from table 1..

```
OSHIKANGO   OSH 1
WINDHOEK 1  WHA 18
WINDHOEK 2  WHB 8
WINDHOEK 3  WHC 2
WINDHOEK 4  WHD 4
```

with this sample data, SUM(Total) is 33. what i want in table 2 is this..

```
OSHIKANGO   OSH 1     3.03030
WINDHOEK 1  WHA 18    54.5454
WINDHOEK 2  WHB 8     24.2424
WINDHOEK 3  WHC 2     etc
WINDHOEK 4  WHD 4
```

seems it should be simpler than this and hope i don't have to go as far as using a Transaction/cursor loop..

Comment: Change the datatype of [Percent] column as decimal(7,4) or decimal(8,5). If the calculated [Percent] value is 100 then you will get 'Airthmetic overflow error'.

Comment: I would recommend NOT storing this calculated value. What happens when a row is deleted or updated? This is why we don't store computed values and instead do this at runtime. If it wasn't using an aggregate I would suggest using a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your query a bit like below, by getting the percent calculation separately and do a `JOIN` with it later

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Result (PrintData, Acronym, Total, [Percent]) 
select t1.PrintData, 
t1.Acronym, 
t1.Total, 
tab.computed
from Temp t1
join
(
select PrintData, 
cast(t.Total as decimal(7,5)) / SUM(t.Total) * 100  as computed 
from Temp t 
group by PrintData, Total 
) tab on t1.PrintData = tab.PrintData;
```

Comment: Aren't you still going to run into integer division issues since both t.Total and SUM(t.Total) are ints?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, Yes, didn't noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is casting problem, try this query :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Result
SELECT PrintData,
       Acronym,
       Sum(Total) [total],
       Round(Sum(Total) / Cast((SELECT Sum(Total)
                                FROM   temp) AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) * 100, 4) [Percent]
FROM   temp
GROUP  BY PrintData,Acronym
```

Also I see you are group by `Total` too. in that case you can use this :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Result
SELECT *,Round((Sum(Total)OVER(partition BY PrintData, Acronym)) / Cast(Sum(Total) OVER() AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) * 100, 4) AS [percent]
FROM   temp
```

Answer (score 0):

convert both to decimal (7,5)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Result
    (PrintData, Acronym, Total, [Percent]) 
select *, (convert(decimal(7,5),Total) / 
(select SUM(convert(decimal(7,5),Total)) * 100  AS [percent]   FROM temp))
from Temp 
group by PrintData, Acronym, Total
```